# Where is the developer command prompt for Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Where is the developer command prompt for visual studio 2013 express for web?

I have been unable to find any answer to my question. I have searched the entire internet with no resolution. Including the questions on this site. The developer command prompt does not exist on my computer...

The developer command prompt does NOT exist in my visual studio tools, it does not exist even on my computer. The only command prompt on my computer that i know is the regular cmd prompt.

I am on windows 8.1 and have been working in VS2013 express for web.

Can anyone give me insight into where i can find the developer command prompt for the VS2013 express for **WEB**?

Answer (score 2):

This prompt is replaced by a batch file arguments
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat""

Though there is shortcut exists for that
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\Shortcuts\Developer Command Prompt for VS2013.exe file

Answer (score 1):

The developer command prompt is just a shortcut to %comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" - NOTE, this is Visual Studio 2012, change from 11.0 to 12.0 for VS 2013.

%compsec% takes you to the visual studio folder%com - not sure what the /k does, but I am sure Google knows.

The file is simply a bunch of determination statements for the framework and some path setting statements.

In other words, even if the file is missing, you can build one that does what you need off the normal cmd.exe. But I would look in the directory in question first.

EDIT: 
The file essentially sets the PATH, INCLUDE, LIB and LIBPATH so you can access the Visual Studio and .NET bits. I could copy the text, but it would be like handing you a gun, as I am not sure what is available on Visual Studio that is not available on Express for Web. Thus far, I don't think you have shown the initiative to ask the right questions to show capability in editing the file, so it becomes a support issue I don't have time to work with.

Thus the question "what are you trying to do?"

Comment: The bat file does not exist.

Comment: i even installed vs 2012, express for web and there is still no developer command prompt

Comment: %ComSpec% is an environment variable that points to cmd.exe.  It's available in any prompt.  /k will run the specified command and leave the prompt running afterwards.

Comment: says the file does not exist.. when i navigate to that folder, there are no tools, only the builder notification

Comment: What is your goal? What are you trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to open up the visual studio 2012 command prompt for vs2012 web express. none of the recommended solutions out there answer myquestion.

Comment: "I am trying to open up the Visual Studio 2012 command prompt" is not a goal, in and of itself. There is a reason you want to open the command prompt, unless you are just curious. You want to accomplish something. What is that something?